# How to pronounce the "dr" sound in the middle of words

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I can pronounce it when it's at the start of a word as in "drive", but when it's in the middle, as in "bedroom" or "Andrew" the "r kind of fades away and I only say a "j" or a "j"' schwa and a normal "r" sound. How can I pronounce this better? And should I even be saying a "j" sound or is a "d" more appropriate in the middle?

Comment: "Andrew" can be pronounced with a "j" (ˈænˌdʒɹʊ̈u), but it can also be pronounced with a "d". I've never heard "bedroom" pronounced with a "j". Not being able to think of any other "j" words offhand, I'm wondering whether "Andrew" isn't a special case.

Comment: @Lachlan Dominic: As a native speaker, I obviously *think* I'm enunciating a /d/ sound in, say, ***redress***. But if I pay attention to where my tongue goes in relaxed casual speech, i can see (feel! :) that actually I don't bother pushing the tip of my tongue forward as far as I would when normally producing that sound. Presumably because I "know" at some visceral level that I'm gonna have to immediately follow it with some kind of /r/ (which as a "non-rhotic", I'm *very* sloppy/lazy about articulating clearly! :). It just saves "tongue gymnastics" to fudge / downplay the /d/. Laziness.

Comment: But my advice to a *learner* (non-native speaker) would be that you should still learn how to enunciate this consonant pair "correctly". Like most native speakers (I assume) I can "exaggeratedly" make the distinction between ***reJress*** and ***reDress*** without having to spell out the actual letters. It shouldn't be seen as a shortcut for nns to avoid ever needing to generate that particular consonant pair. Offhand I don't know of any "minimal pair" where the J/D difference distinguishes different words, but they might well exist.

Comment: [Tricky Blends: "dr or j?"](https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Tricky-Blends-dr-or-j-Picture-and-Word-Sort-554779)

Comment: I think it's much the same with J/D after /n/. I bet a lot of people actually enunciate /d/ as /j/ when they say ***endure***. But I'd say they can all articulate / exaggerate the difference between between ***endure*** and ***injure***.

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Remember that to most Americans, _endure_ either has /dʒ/ or /d/; /dj/ is primarily a British thing.

Comment: If the /d/ and /r/ are in the same syllable, like *Andrew* or *raindrop*, you can pronounce them as "jr": /reɪndʒrɑp/. If they're not in the same syllable, like *bedroom* or *fundraiser*, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question; you may pronounce these better if you think of them as compound words though some are not. The small space given before starting the word *Room* after *Bed* should help focus your pronunciation of the words. Similar with *An* and *Drew*.